# Is there a way to export a list of Data Frames to json?

Tags: pandas

I wonder if there is a way to save a list of Data Frames into a json file, instead of having a loop to save each df into a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it:

```
with open('my_file.json', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json.dumps([df.to_dict() for df in list_of_df]))
```

Each data frame has to be converted to a dict first and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to concatenate everything first? Assuming they have the same column structure.

```py
full_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Then export to json.

Comment: I need to keep the df's separated, that's why I need to save the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function for that **to_json**

You can either iterate on the data frames or concatenate them

```
df.to_json('Path to exported JSON file\File Name.json')
```

Comment: Yes, I know that function but it only works for Data Frames. I do not wish to concatenate my Data Frames, hence the question. How to export a list of df?

Comment: Iterating would result in lots of files. The ideal solution is to save one single file with the whole list.

Comment: You have many data frames and you want to extract them to one file, so you need to join them before the single export in some way and the way to do it is concatenate

Comment: No, precisely, I need them not to be joined in one DF. See above, I found the answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("dfAsJson.json", "w") as text:
    for dataframe in [df,df2]:
        text.write(dataframe.to_json())
        text.write("\n")
```

So this will save the json of each df on its own line as a json file (although a txt file would make more sense in this case). You just have to change the for loop with whatever your df are called.

Comment: if you have the list already then just replace [df, df2] with the list name.

Comment: you can type ```text.write({insert-df-name-here}.to_json())``` for every df (which is completely pointless).